# Is there any difference in performance of resultset and Scrollable ResultSet?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

In my application I have to fetch records and need to put them in to 2D array. I have to fire two queries first to find out the count so that I can initialize the array and second is to fetch the data. It results in performance hit. I need solution to improve the performance.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a suitable implementation of the [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We have not used the entity to hold the data. So we have to use the 2D array. This is the reason I am not using the List.

Comment: i don't understand this answer. trashgod's question to me seems on target. Can you expand on why you need to use arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to fire two queries first to
>   find out the count so that I can
>   initialize the array and second is to
>   fetch the data.

You can combine your 2 queries as:

```
select *,(select count(*) from table) as counting from table;
```

Comment: Will it make any difference in performance as we are firing two queries?

Comment: It might depend if the DB is smart enough to know it's "really" just one query.  I'm curious, why do you have to know the result set size up front?  So you can shape your 2D array correctly?

Comment: Yes, correct!!We have not used the entity to hold the data. So we have to use the 2D array. This is the reason I am not using the List. :(

Comment: Can you read the rs into a plain List and then get the size and create/fill your 2D array?  I don't know how big your rs but it may be less expensive than the extra count(*) query.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using a suitable `Collection`, such as `List<List<Object>>`. For improved type-safety, consider using [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html); the query example is near the bottom.